# Chamar uma dll em javaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dll

Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de se comunicar com uma dll usando javaScript ou angularjs ?

Comment: AngularJS **é JavaScript**. Você quer acessar a DLL numa aplicação cliente ou está falando de NodeJS?

Comment: um aplicação cliente

Comment: Então é impossível. Já imaginou a lambança que seria que qualquer código JavaScript pudesse ter acesso à máquina de quem visita a página?

Comment: mesmo sendo um dll criada por min onde essa mesma seria consumida por uma aplicação em delphi.

Comment: Se ela vai ser consumida por uma aplicação em Delphi não tem porquê tentar acessar ela por JS, né?

Comment: estamos migrando uma aplicação em delphi para web  e queríamos a partir dessa  aplicação web chamar um executável na maquina do cliente.  e essa foi uma ideia que tivemos mais como não temos muito conhecimento com dll e javaScript , não sabemos se e possível.

Comment: Não é possível.

Comment: Como o Matheus já comentou, isso é impossível, porém você pode tentar chamar pelo backend, ou até mesmo tentar a solução que está neste link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11517319/call-dll-methods-from-javascript

Comment: Uma coisa que eu falo sempre. As pessoas precisam parecer de querer fazer tudo pra web. Web é solução para algumas coisas, não para tudo.

Comment: Bigown  obrigado  por nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aderbal, JavaScript é um linguagem de FrontEnd e não interage com DLL´s, as DLL's podem ser acessadas pelo BackEnd do servidor, processar a informação e de [alguma forma](https://dzone.com/articles/data-exchange-format-between) passar para o FrontEnd o desejado.
[Essa leitura](https://www.quora.com/Which-programming-languages-are-front-end-and-which-ones-are-back-end) pode te ajudar, ela te ajuda a entender os conceitos de linguagem e qual é o propósito de cada uma.

Comment: `JavaScript é um linguagem de FrontEnd` *cof cof* [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) *cof cof*